# Prevent Autohotkey multiple evaluation

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following Autohotkey script:

```
^d:: ^l
^l:: ^g
```

My intention is to have 2 keymaps: <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>; but when I run the script, <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is not map to <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> but will be map to <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> as autohotkey evaluate <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>.

Is there any way to prevent Autohotkey from evaluating the keymap multiple time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts call each other, which is a common problem in AutoHotKey.
To prevent this from happening, you have to add a $ in front of the hotkey that you don't want to be launched by ahk

```
^d:: ^l ; This script will trigger the next one
$^l:: ^g ; The $ sign prevents that another AutoHotKey script can launch this.
```